# Problema con consume() en javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estaba intentando validar un textField para que no se pueda ingresar números, sin embargo, aún me deja hacerlo.

```
protected void onHelloButtonClick(KeyEvent e) {
    

    if(!Character.isLetter(e.getCharacter().charAt(0))){
        e.consume();
    }
    

}
```

El problema es que si me reconoce cuando ingreso un número, entra al condicional y se ejecuta el método consume() pero no pasa nada y aún me deja ingresar números.

Answer (score 0):

en este caso deberias leer el codigo del caracter y compararlo con la tabla ASCII donde los numeros estan desde el 48 hasta el 57 y todo lo que se escriba guardarlo en una variable para siempre validar primero y luego colocar el texto ya que el evento sucede despues de la escritura. Aca te dejo un ejemplo.

```
@FXML
private TextField escritura;

StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder(); // Se guarda todo lo que se escribe

@FXML
void ESCRIBIR(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode().getCode() > 47 && event.getCode().getCode() <= 57){
        System.out.println("Es un numero: "+event.getCode().getChar());
    } else {
        texto.append(event.getCode().getChar()); // se guarda el caracter
    }

    escritura.setText(texto.toString());// se actualiza el textfield con lo guardado
    escritura.positionCaret(escritura.getText().length());// y se coloca el marcador al final del texto

}
```